# Git- local master branch appears to be broken

Tags: django, git, git-branch

I am working on a Python/ Django project, using Git to manage my version control.

On the live server, the website currently works as expected, however, I have made a couple of changes to the layout/ presentation of one of the `views` on my local copy.

To do this, when my local master branch was up to date with the live version, I created a new branch from master called `pipelineProject`, and started working on that branch. While making changes on `pipelineProject`, I 'broke' the website during the course of making changes, and had to revert that branch to the state of master a couple of times.

I have now got my `pipelineProject` branch to a state where the changes I wanted to make work correctly- I have run `git add -A` and `git commit -m 'message'` to ensure that my working `pipelineProject` branch is backed up.

However, after backing up `pipelineProject`, I then checked out `master`, as I obviously wanted to merge my changes with `master`, and before merging my changes, I tried loading my website in the browser while on `master` branch- but for some reason this is now broken... although the website loads, all of the styling has disappeared- and the page just displays a list of the HTML elements used in the page (hyperlinks, titles & a few variable names from the code)

The live version of the website is still in the same working state as it was before I started working on these changes, so I tried switching to my local `master` branch, and running `git pull origin master` to update my local `master` copy with the copy that is currently running on the server.

When I did this, git displayed a message saying:

> Already up-to-date

I don't understand why this is... if my local master is up-to-date, then why am I able to view the website correctly on the live server, but when I view it on my local server, it doesn't display correctly...?

When I view the website locally on my `pipelineProject` branch it all works correctly (and the changes that I have made are displayed as expected), but I don't want to merge my `pipelineProject` branch into my local `master` branch in case I lose the changes that I have successfully made.

Why is it that my local `master` is broken, when the `live` master works, even though the two are identical? How can I fix this before pushing my changes to the live server?

**Edit**

Just a thought: since my `pipelineProject` branch seems be working correctly, could I replace my local master branch with this one, and then push that to the server?

Is there a reason why my local master would be broken even though it is up-to-date with the live one when the live one works?

Comment: Did you change anything that is not in the versioning? Like renamed css/js files without calling collectstatic command. Do have the same django settings live and locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your questions:

1. Yes, you can replace master branch with pipelineProject branch. First you should make pipelineProject branch to track origin/master, use `git checkout pipelineProject` and `git branch pipelineProject -u origin/master`, then delete local master branch `git branch –D master`, finally rename pipelineProject to master `git branch -m pipelineProject master`
2. Yes, there has a reason for it. It’s caused by the local master branch is ahead of origin/master branch for remote (you can use `git status` to check), and you can view commits which are ahead of the origin/master, use `git log origin/master..master`. So for your situation you need to drop the “broken” commit, you can use `git reset --hard <commit id which you want go back>`(if you do't willing to delete master branch)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your local & remote master are in same commit-sha
   `$ git checkout pipelineProject       # go to your pipelineProject branch`
   `$ git branch -D master               # delete the local master branch`

   Then go to online and copy the master's last commit sha
   `$ git checkout paste-commit-sha-here    # go to the remote master's last commit`
   `$ git checkout -b master                # create & checkout local master branch`
2. Replace local master with `pipelineProject` and push to server

   `$ git checkout pipelineProject       # go to your pipelineProject branch`
   `$ git branch -D master               # delete the local master branch`
   `$ git checkout -b master             # create & checkout new local master`
   `$ git push -f origin master          # push to server forcely`